# Spring micrometer tracing not honoring parentSpanId or converting `X-B3-spanId` recieved in headers to parentSpanId

Tags: java, spring, micrometer, spring-micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I'm using micrometer tracing with Brave as my vendor. I observed that micrometer is not honoring parentSpanId in any of the 3 below scenarios:

1. When I create a `nextSpan` within the application, I expect the previous `spanId` to be present in MDC as `parentSpanId`.
2. When my service is called by another service and the request Header contains `X-B3-SpanId`, I expect this ID to be available in MDC as `parentSpanId`.

But neither of these are happening.

Following is my application.properties file:

```
server.port=8085
spring.application.name=exampleApp

logging.pattern.console=%d{yyyy-MM-dd }, [[[%mdc]]] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n

management.tracing.sampling.probability=0.0
management.tracing.propagation.type=B3_MULTI

logging.level.root=info
```

There's no customization on top of this and I am totally relying on the Spring Auto configuration of micrometer..

I tried adding the following property after reading the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/tracing/TracingProperties.Baggage.Correlation.html#getFields()) which read

> List of fields that should be correlated with the logging context. That means that these fields would end up as key-value pairs in e.g. MDC.

```
management.tracing.baggage.correlation.fields=parentSpanId,X-B3-ParentSpanId,parentId
```

But I see no changes in MDC. How do I get this working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Micrometer is not honoring the property. This seems like bug in Micrometer. I have reported the same in [github](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/issues/420)

However, I figured this could be configured by creating a spring bean.

```
import brave.baggage.BaggageFields;
import brave.baggage.CorrelationScopeConfig;
import brave.baggage.CorrelationScopeCustomizer;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnProperty;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.annotation.Order;


@Configuration
public class BraveConfig {

    @Bean
    CorrelationScopeCustomizer parentSpanIdCustomizer() {
        return (builder) -> builder.add(
                CorrelationScopeConfig.SingleCorrelationField.newBuilder(BaggageFields.PARENT_ID)
                        .name("parentSpanId").build());
    }
}
```

I have also customized the `parentId` to be added as `parentSpanId` in MDC.

This bean will be picked up by `BraveAutoConfiguration#mdcCorrelationScopeDecoratorBuilder` during autoconfiguration and customized accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

> When I create a nextSpan within the application, I expect the previous spanId to be present in MDC as parentSpanId.

This was an old behavior in Sleuth, I think we stopped doing this quite a while ago and go with the Brave default: `traceId` and `spanId`, see [`CorrelationScopeDecorator`](https://github.com/openzipkin/brave/blob/9f4f166f97a3645e7514c0db920eb02bb3666e7d/brave/src/main/java/brave/baggage/CorrelationScopeDecorator.java#L79-L84)

As you already found out you need to create a `CorrelationScopeCustomizer` but you can do this in a simpler way:

```java
@Bean
CorrelationScopeCustomizer parentIdCorrelationScopeCustomizer() {
    return builder -> builder.add(SingleCorrelationField.create(BaggageFields.PARENT_ID));
}
```

> When my service is called by another service and the request Header contains X-B3-SpanId, I expect this ID to be available in MDC as parentSpanId.

I'm not sure how is this different to your previous point, if you do the above and create a child span, in its scope the MDC will contain the parentId.

Fields set in `management.tracing.baggage.correlation.fields` or `management.tracing.baggage.remote-fields` will be in the MDC if you create a baggage scope manually or a baggage is sent in the headers.

Comment: "Fields set in management.tracing.baggage.correlation.fields or management.tracing.baggage.remote-fields will be in the MDC"

This is not working @Jonatan. This is precisely why I had to bring it to your attention in Github. This seems like a genuine bug. parentId is not showing up in MDC despite adding this property.

Comment: Please read that line again, I said: "... will be in the MDC IF you create a baggage scope manually or a baggage is sent in the headers." In your case neither is happening (`X-B3-ParentSpanId` header is not part of the baggage).

Comment: Ah! But then, what's the point of the property if I am forced to add a customization bean anyway?

Comment: I mean `BraveAutoConfiguration#correlationFieldsCorrelationScopeCustomizer` does create baggage for the fields defined in the property. isn't this enough for the parentId to be present in MDC without the need to define `CorrelationScopeCustomizer` bean? Moreover, defining it both in the property and a customizer bean for the same field will throw `IllegalArgumentException: Baggage Field already added: parentId`

Comment: The property is for baggage fields that you manually set or coming in as an http **baggage** header (not any header, it needs to be a baggage header). For Brave every field is a baggage field including trace/span/parentId for Sleuth/Micrometer Tracing, the baggage is only what I described above.