Log W3C's parentId in Spring Boot 3 with micrometer/brave bridge
We're currently implementing W3C tracing and a requirement is that we log the span ID, trace ID and parent ID. Logging span and trace is easily done with
pattern="Micrometer Trace ID[%X{traceId}] Span [%X{spanId}]..."

but I cannot access the parentId with either [%X{parentId}] or mdc.parentId. I haven't found a way to make the parentId available for logging, what am I missing?
Thanks!

Did you check if parentId is present in MDC when the log is printed? you can try System.out.println(MDC.getCopyOfContextMap()); and see everything that is present in the MDC. Maybe the name is different, or maybe the parentId is not present at all which is a different issue to look at.

I think I had run into this issue in the past and had posted this question : https://stackoverflow.com/q/77389421/8283737
This might help you.

Yes I checked the MDC but you're right, the question is pretty much the same. No idea why it didn't pop up on my search beforehand, thanks for the hint! Your solution works like a charm, I had also tried to add it via configuration which failed. I think the configuration only passes request headers to MDC and as parentId is technically not a request header, it doesn't work that easily.
